# How to handle a url-encoded named outlet specification in the url for Angular?

Tags: angular, url-routing

On my Angular website, I have an app which uses a named outlet, and the site itself uses an unnamed outlet as the main page outlet, where that app is one of the pages. An example url path: `/tools/pg/color-visualizer/(tool-is:m-color-visualizer)?color=%231a5d84`. Note that the path name is `color-visualizer` and the child component path is `m-color-visualizer`.

However, I've noticed that I'm getting some hits on my website that look like this: `/tools/pg/color-visualizer/%28tool-is:m-color-visualizer%29?color=%23ffe2ff`. Those are causing 404 errors. What I'd like to do is setup a redirect to move that back to the appropriate route. My route configuration looks like this:

```
const outlet = 'tool-is';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':toolTitle',
        component: ToolContainerComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'm-color-visualizer',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '../tools/color-visualizer/color-visualizer.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.ColorVisualizerToolModule),
                canActivate: [ToolModuleGuardService],
                outlet,
                data: {
                    toolKey: 'colorVisualizer',
                },
            },
        ],
    }
];
```

However, all attempts which I've tried have failed. Are there any recommendations on the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried adding a URL matcher & decoding URL with decodeURIComponent() in your routing config?

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding the url directly just to match it: "%28tool-is:m-color-visualizer%29?color=%23ffe2ff", but I could not get any way of making it work with adding that as a child or top level path.

Comment: Did you solved it? I have same problem